# What's the difference between mysqli_fetch and query->fetch?

Tags: php, mysqli

I would like to know the difference between `mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);` and `$query->fetch_assoc();`

this is my query:

```
$checkquery = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT admin_id FROM admin WHERE name='$username' AND password='md5($password)'") or 
die (mysqli_error($con));

$correct = $checkquery->fetch_assoc();
if (!$correct)
    $errors[] = 'Incorrect login.';
```

It worked for me when i write it as: `$correct = $checkquery->fetch_assoc();`,
but When I change this to `$correct = mysqli_fetch_assoc($checkquery);`, It doesn't work for me anymore.

Comment: Try reading PHP documentation than asking here..
There is all what you need to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mysqli_fetch_assoc` is **procedural** aproach , 
`fetch_assoc()` is **object oriented** style

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to know the difference between `mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);` and `$query->fetch_assoc();`

there is no significant difference.

> When I change this to $correct = mysqli_fetch_assoc($checkquery);, It doesn't work for me anymore.

Most likely you have changed something else too.

Turn error reporting on and see what is wrong with your code at whole, as though it was written from scratch, not changed.